# gaussian fit on multiple peak in a spectrum

Tags: python, plot, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a spectrum on which I tried to do a gaussian fit on, but when I plotted it, I realized that this was not a single peak, but two or three very close peaks.
This is my code:

```
          from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
          #weighted mean
          mean = sum(velo_peak * spec_peak) / sum(spec_peak)
          sigma = np.sqrt(sum(spec_peak * (velo_peak - mean)**2) / sum(spec_peak))
          
          def Gauss(velo_peak, a, x0, sigma):
              return a * np.exp(-(velo_peak - x0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
          
          p0=[max(spec_peak), mean, sigma]
          popt,pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, velo_peak, spec_peak, p0)
          print("the velocities at the peak are",velo_peak)
          plt.plot(velo_peak*1e-9,spec_peak,'k')
          plt.plot(velo_peak*1e-9, Gauss(velo_peak, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
```

[image]

My question is: Is there a method to do a fitting on multiple close peaks

I edited this question so that its more clear:
I want to do a gaussian fit for both of the peaks, as it can be seen from the picture, the function did only a fit on a single peak. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but it may depend on how you look at it: it will, in a way, average those peaks, since you've suggested to model it with a single peak, and the algorithm will simply do that as best as possible.

Comment: So the question is rather: do you want to fit a single Gaussian, or do you want to fit the three single peaks? If the latter, with what do you want to model those?

Comment: I want to calculate the FWHM, so just wanted to make sure that the function takes into account the neighboring peaks so that the FWHM can be accurate.

Comment: The FWHM of what: the combined peaks, one single peak, the FWHM of each peak (independently)?

Comment: Also, why don't you just try for a start? Play around a bit with the initial values of the fitting parameters to see if that changes the results, and overplot the fit on top of your data. Calculate and plot the residuals, chisq and other relevant fit results. Further, since you mention a spectrum and I see `velo` as a variable (velocity?), be sure whether a Gaussian is a correct model for your line. Perhaps a Lorentzian is a better model for your line, or even a Voigt function?

Comment: okay, so I wanted to check before answering. I need to find the FWHM of each individual peak, and as for the best profile for fitting, yes the gaussian is the most suitable.

Comment: I suppose to do that kind of fitting i need to set my initial guess parameters and try with them, also i need to modify my gauss function so that it has two formulas, so its something like this: a * np.exp(-(velo_peak - x0_1)**2 / (2 * sigma_1**2)) + a * np.exp(-(velo_peak - x0_2)**2 / (2 * sigma_2**2)). Is this correct?

Comment: You would have to do a fit with three Gaussians (and possibly a (level?) background), each Gaussian corresponding to one of your peaks. Make sure the initial parameters of your Gaussians are close to the expected values, so each Gaussian corresponds to the right peak.

Comment: Your given code in your comment fitting sample misses two things: 1/ the amplitude `a` is the same between the two Gaussians; I assume this can (and should) vary, so use `a1` and `a2`; 2/ you mention (and show three peaks) in your question. Unless you just want to fit the two largest peaks, include a third Gaussian as well. Other than, assuming `velo_peak` is your independent variable, your formulation is correct. (Note that the *name* `velo_peak` suggests that it is a fit parameter, not your independent variable; the code in your questions shows it's indeed the independent variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Sample the gaussian distribution at the given discrete timstamps and substract it from the original signal. Then it will find the "second" heap.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but just to make sure I understood, I do the Gaussian fit on the peak, then subtract it from the spectrum, then re-do the Gaussian fit on the second peak?

Comment: Yes, but the gaussian fit is a continous function, so you have to sample it. Then you can re-do the whole process. If you need, you can save the created samples that you substracted, so you can reconstruct your original signal. Hope this helps.